# ddev not starting correctly

Tags: php, docker, ddev, craftcms

I am new to ddev and am using mac os 13. I used the following tutorial.
https://ddev.com/get-started/
But when I run the ddev start command, ddev doesn't work properly.
Related to this, the docker container also does not start properly
The command gives the following error.

The ddev version is v1.22.1

**ddev logs -s web**

````
+ disable_xdebug
Disabled xdebug
+ phpenmod assert
+ ls /var/www/html
ls: cannot open directory '/var/www/html': Stale file handle
+ echo '/var/www/html does not seem to be healthy/mounted; docker may not be mounting it., exiting'
/var/www/html does not seem to be healthy/mounted; docker may not be mounting it., exiting
+ exit 101
+ trap - SIGTERM
+ kill -- -1```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Docker Desktop is not working for you, or perhaps you haven't given Docker Desktop permissions to share your home directory.  You need to make sure Docker Desktop is sharing your directory:

[image: Docker Desktop Sharing Configuration]

Make sure your project is in your home directory, where permissions are "normal" for things like this. So your project might be in `/Users/<you>/projects/<yourproject>`.

If you still have trouble, Colima or Orbstack in that case. See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/docker-installation/ - but put your project in your home directory.